# Polymer iron-list

Tags: polymer, iron-list

I want to display a grid of items with top and bottom margins using iron-list but no results.I'm using polymer 2.0 and iron-list 2.0.16. 
The margins are not displayed but appear in devtools when i highlight any of the items in iron-list. I don't know what i'm not doing right.I tried fixing it but no success.
      ...

```
  :host {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
  }

  .country {
    height: 50px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 16px 0;

  }

  iron-list {
    height: 100vh;
  }
</style>
<data-story-data region="africa" countries="{{countries}}"></data-story data>
<iron-list items="[[countries]]" as="country" scroll-target="document" grid>
  <template>
    <div class="country">
      <p>[[country.name]]</p>

    </div>
    <!--
    <paper-card>
      <div class="card-content">
        <div>[[country.name]]</div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-actions">
        <a href="[[rootPath]]detail/country/[[country.name]]/[[country.alpha2Code]]/about" tabindex="-1">
          <paper-button raised>view</paper-button>
        </a>
      </div>
    </paper-card>
  -->
  </template>
</iron-list>
```

...

this is what i get
[image: rendered items without margin 16px at top and bottom]

what can i do to make the 16px top and bottom margins work. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list items are displaying 0px margins because `iron-list` overrides them:

**iron-list.html**

```
<style>

    /* ... */

    #items > ::slotted(*) {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        margin: 0; /* Here */
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        will-change: transform;
    }

    /* ... */

</style>
```

Try instead to wrap your cards in a container and use its padding instead of margin to obtain the spacing you want:

```
<style>
  .country {
      padding: 16px 0;
  }
</style>

<iron-list items="[[countries]]" as="country" scroll-target="document" grid>
  <template>
    <div class="country">
        <paper-card>
          <div class="card-content">
            <div>[[country.name]]</div>
          </div>
          <div class="card-actions">
            <a href="[[rootPath]]detail/country/[[country.name]]/[[country.alpha2Code]]/about" tabindex="-1">
              <paper-button raised>view</paper-button>
            </a>
          </div>
        </paper-card>
    </div>
  </template>
</iron-list>
```

Comment: Your solution worked. Thanks. I guess this must b a new iron-list behavior cos i never experienced this using polymer 1.x.x. Do you know any resources to learn more on using polymer to build robust applications including testing.